# How to speed up data transfer between Portable HD and NAS (QNAP)?

Tags: nas, rsync, file-transfer, qnap

I am trying to transfer data from a Western Digital USB2 Drive to a QNAP TS-212E. I am transfering the data between the portable HD and the NAS using rsync (see following command).

```
 rsync -v -r -h -size-only --progress /share/USBDisk1/ /share/Backup/
```

The drive has a size of 100GB and it's been copying for more than 24 hours and at the current speed it will take multiple days. Most of the files on the portable HD are photos and each of them transfer at 300-500kb/sec.

The CPU of the NAS is almost to 0%. Is there something I am doing wrong? How can I speed up the data transfer?

Thanks!

Comment: How are the health of the drives? Bad clusters could give poor performance like you're experiencing.

Comment: Good question! I just checked and everything looks good.

Comment: I have the same issue with my QNAP. It's very very slow when copying to the share, but only from USB disks. Is it faster when you try over a networked computer?

Comment: Check your network connection.. 300-500 kbps sounds like maybe your NIC, router or one of the ports is operating at 10mbps..  Maybe one of your ports on the router is failing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my little NAS CPU was dying. So I connected my external HD to my laptop, plugged in my laptop in the router and now I get a transfer rate of 3-4Mb/sec.